# Actionscript 3 Call to a possibly undefined method

Tags: actionscript-3, class, movieclip

Here is the problem, the object is moved together with the clicked object. I want it to be moveable following the mouse pointer, but let the clicked object stays. so when an object is clicked, there will be 2 objects in the stage(the static and moving one).

I think I've figured it out by adding a new object to be moved. in function onClickHero I've tried movingHero = new heroes but it says "call to a possibly undefined method heroes". My question is there any other way how to make another clone of the clicked object since I made it in array? And why does movingHero = new heroes doesn't work?

I'm still amateur at classes. Sorry if it's messed up. Thanks for helping.

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip
import flash.events.MouseEvent
import flash.events.Event
import flash.display.Sprite

public class Hero {
    private var heroesArray:Array;
    private var heroContainer:Sprite = new Sprite;
    private var hero1:MovieClip = new Hero1();
    private var hero2:MovieClip = new Hero2();
    private var moveHero:Boolean = false;
    private var movingHero:MovieClip;
    private var _money:Money =  new Money();
    private var _main:Main;

    public function Hero(main:Main) 
    {   _main = main;
        heroesArray = [hero1,hero2];
        heroesArray.forEach(addHero);
    }

    public function addHero(heroes:MovieClip,index:int,array:Array):void
    {
        heroes.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playerMoving);
        heroes.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chooseHero);
    }

    public function playerMoving(e:Event):void
    {
        if (moveHero == true)
        {
            movingHero.x = _main.mouseX;
            movingHero.y = _main.mouseY;
        }
    }

    public function chooseHero(e:MouseEvent):void
    {   
        var heroClicked:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;
        var cost:int = _main._money.money ;
        if(cost >= 10 && moveHero == false)
        {
            _main._money.money -= 10;
            _main._money.addText(_main);
            onClickHero(heroClicked);
            moveHero = true;
        }

    }

    public function onClickHero(heroes:MovieClip):void
    {
        movingHero =  heroes;
        heroContainer.addChild(movingHero);

    }


    public function displayHero(stage:Object):void
    {   
        stage.addChild(heroContainer);

        for (var i:int = 0; i<2;i++)
            {
                stage.addChild(heroesArray[i]);
                heroesArray[i].x = 37;
                heroesArray[i].y = 80+i*70;
                heroesArray[i].width=60;
                heroesArray[i].height=55;
                heroesArray[i].buttonMode = true;
            }
    }

  } 
}
```

EDIT: I've tried to make movingHero = new Hero1(); but since I don't know which hero will be clicked so I can't just use Hero1 from library. and If I use movingHero = heroClicked I only get the value of hero1 which is a var from Hero1 movieclip. So, is there any way to call the movie clip from library the same as which hero was clicked in stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seemingly want to clone an object while not knowing its type. If that object also containg game logic, it's not the best idea to say spawn new heroes of either type, this might make a mess of your code. But if not, you can get the exact class of the object given, and make an object of that class via the following code:

```
public function onClickHero(heroes:MovieClip):void
{
    if (!heroes) {
        trace('heroes is null!');
        return;
    }
    var heroClass:Class = getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(heroes)) as Class;
    movingHero = new heroClass(); // instantiate that class
    heroContainer.addChild(movingHero);
    // movingHero.startDrag(); if needed
}
```

Don't forget to clean up the `movingHero` once it's no longer needed.

Comment: umm I still don't understand about creating new class inside a function and that prototype. can you please explain? and yes I want to have the clone but isn't the type is just a targeted movieclip which is inside an array? (I'm still not sure about these things, sorry). Anyway thanks a lot for answering but it produced a new error at the heroClass:Class line . TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.

Comment: No, they type of an object is not necessarily a MovieClip. When you call `new SomeClass()`, the new object is created and receives the type `SomeClass`. That type might also be interpreted as any of its predecessors, say if you have `public class SomeClass extends MovieClip`, then that object can be interpreted as `MovieClip`, as well as `Sprite` or `DisplayObject` or `EventDispatcher`, as these are predecessors for `MovieClip`. About the error - hmmmm, weird. Maybe I've written 'prototype' wrongly, or you're passing a null in there.

Comment: Please check updated answer, and tell what trace do you receive.

Comment: this is the result of the trace Oh my, heroes don't have a prototype!
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: so that heroClass can have a value of being a movie clip or another? how about that prototype.constructor? I've never seen that before. can you please explain that too? thanks!

Comment: Actually, to make it clear I want to make it like this: public function onClickHero(heroes:MovieClip):void
  { 
   movingHero =  new Hero1();
   
   heroContainer.addChild(movingHero);} but since I don't know which hero will be clicked I can't just write movingHero = new Hero1(); right? Is there any way to add new movie clip from library the same one with which hero was clicked? is there any flash vocab that I haven't known for this? thanks once again.

Comment: Okay, try this approach (updated answer). You would need to import definitions for both `getDefinitionByName()` and `getQualifiedClassName()` for this to compile. Please reply if this won't work.

Comment: Got another error: Call to a possibly undefined method getDefinitionByName() and getQualifiedClassName. I'll reply for sure anyway because I haven't found any solution.

Comment: `import flash.utils.*` should fix that.

Comment: wow thanks a lot!! finally it's solved. just one more question. what are those things for? I seriously don't have any idea about those things. I only learn actionscript by trying things out myself and from a really basic flash book in my computer lesson at school. So I think I've missed a lot of things such as those. can you please explain it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just noticed something, why should movingHero be cleaned up? I've tried placing the heroes on the stage field, and when I clicked again another hero, the movieclip of movingHero have been changed too, so it won't be taking up memory, will it? or does the last clicked still remain and will take memory? Sorry for taking your time

Comment: It should not, if it does not have any attached permanent links, like listeners or more references. So yes, while you are using that `movingHero` for the sole purpose of displaying an extra movie clip, you should be safe. And about those things, it's just a method to get information about an object if you're not knowing what it is and what it could possibly be.

Comment: ohh i see. so it's used to call the base class of an object. thanks a lot for all the explanation!